# How to get the highest key from dictionary (python)?

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm new to Python and I am having a small problem I want to solve

```
a={"1" : 3, "2" : 3, "6":3}
```

I have this dic and I would like to get the maximum key out of him
for example in the dictionary above I would like to get the key 6 as a value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many ways, one way of doing it is:

```
greatest = max(int(k) for k in a)
```

Or a human readable format, so you can understand the logic:

```
greatest = None
for k in a:
    k = int(k)
    if greatest == None:
        greatest = k
    if k > greatest:
        greatest = k
```

Answer (score 2):

For a simple, functional approach:

```
max(map(int,a))
```

This applies the `int` function to each key of `a` using `map` to convert the keys as strings to integers, then finds the maximum of these using `max`.

Comment: You are missing a parenthesis.

Comment: @AntonvBR Thanks, fixed

Answer (score 1):

If you want the original key (as as string, not an integer), you could simply use [`max`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max) with `int` as key argument:

```
a = {"1" : 3, "2" : 3, "6":3}
max(a, key=int)
# '6'
```